# Java Calling function from other class async

Tags: java, asynchronous

I have a problem. I am trying to call a method from another class async. Here is the function I am trying to call:

```
public class CandlestickDriver {

    public void run(String market, String coin, String period, boolean once, boolean firstRun) {

    }

}
```

And in my MainClass, I have the following code:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(CandlestickDriver::run);
```

But that gives me the error:

> The type CandlestickDriver does not define run() that is applicable
> here

I also don't see a way how I can pass the paramters to that class, so how can I fix this. It's important that I can use some kind of chaining, because when that method is done, I need to call another method, so I found the command `.thenApply()`, but also for that I need to pass paramters.

How can I fix my error and pass parameters?

### UPDATE

I tried the following:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> new CandlestickDriver.run("USDT", "BTC", "1d", once, firstRun));
```

But that give me an error on `supplyAsync` : `The method supplyAsync(Supplier<U>) in the type CompletableFuture is not applicable for the arguments (() -> {})`

And I also get an error on `CandlestickDriver.run`: `CandlestickDriver.run cannot be resolved to a type`

How can I fix this?

Comment: The method is an instance method (not static). You should pass an instance of your class with the method reference. Additionally it takes parameters, so you will probably need something like `supplyAsync(() -> instance.run(args…));`.

Comment: I tried it, but I get 2 errors. Check my update part in my question

Comment: I supplied a full example with comments providing information on what's going on in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax related issue immediately, which is `new CandlestickDriver.run`. This needs to be `new CandlestickDriver().run` as you're instantiating a new object.

Also, `CompletableFuture#supplyAsync` takes a `Supplier<U>` as input, and you're passing `Supplier<void>`, but `void` isn't a type that can be supplied. Since this function doesn't return anything, you don't need to `supplyAsync`, but rather `runAsync`.

```java
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> new CandlestickDriver().run("", "", "", false, false));
```

Comment: And for chaining I can use `.thenApply()`?

Comment: Well since void returns nothing, you can't really use the output from the function as input for another, so you can't chain the output since there isn't any. If you change the type to something other than void, definitely.

Comment: But I have nothing to return? Should I return a null value then?

Comment: Well, it entirely depends on what you want to do after. Do you need the previous result or does it not matter? Do you just want to execute another action AFTER the first one is finished? If so, you can just use `thenRunAsync`, `thenApplyAsync`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full example of how to call `supplyAsync` in the way you're attempting.  I used a class with fewer arguments, but it should indicate what you need to do.

```java
package com.com;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class QuickExample {

   private static final class Runner {
       public void run(String arg) {
           try {
               // Emulate long running task.

               TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3L);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               throw new RuntimeException(e);
           }
           System.out.println(arg);
       }
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
       // Have an instance of your class
       final Runner runner = new Runner();

       // runAsync is also an option if you don't care about any output.
       final CompletableFuture<Object> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
           // Invoke your runner
           runner.run("woof");

           // supplyAsync expects a Callable, which returns a value.
           // Assuming you don't care about the output here, you can just
           // return anything.  This will only affect the generic-type of
           // the returned CompletableFuture<...>. 
           return null;
       });
       
       // Get the result to ensure that it's happened before exiting your
       // program.
       future.get();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, the given information is not complete clear. But propably this is what you try to do.

```
public class CandlestickDriver implements Supplier<String> , Runnable {

public CandlestickDriver(String market, String coin, String period, boolean once, boolean firstRun)  {

    //store parameter into fields
}

@Override
public String get() {
    return "Get it first";
}

@Override
public void run() {

System.out.println("Run..");
    
}
```

}

```
        CandlestickDriver candlestickDriver = new CandlestickDriver("USDT", "BTC", "1d", true, true);
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(candlestickDriver::get).thenRunAsync(candlestickDriver);
```

Comment: Which method do you call with: `.thenRunAsync(candlestickDriver)`?